# Is there a way to solve 'POST internal error 500' from html to node js

Tags: forms, express, nodemailer

Greetings Stack Overflow Community, I 'am:

Fullname: Collymore Dawids
country: Namibia, Swakopmund

Experience
I'm fairly new to programming and how server works.

Problem
I 'am trying to send form data (html) with jQuery to express to my personal email using mailGun API

Front End is pretty solid no problems, its only backend I think!!

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const sendMail = require('./mail.js');
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json())

app.post('/email', (req,res) =>{
//TODO
// send email here
const {fullName,phone,email,subject,message} = req.body; // from jquery to nodejs
console.log('Data:',req.body)

sendMail(fullName,phone,email,subject,message, function(err,data){
    if(err){
        res.status(500).json({message: 'Internal error'});
    }else{
        res.json({message: 'Email sent...!!'})
    }
});
})

// get the html
app.get('/', (req,res) =>{
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/public/Form/form.html'));
})
```

HTML Form

```
<form action="/email" method="POST" class="contact-form">
  <h2>ContactUs</h2>
  <input type="text" id="Fullname" placeholder="Full Name" value="Some 
      text data" name="FullName" ><br>
  <input type="number" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" value="0813405085" name="Phone"><br>
  <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" value="erroldavids33@outlook.com" 
     name="Email"><br>
  <input type="text" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" value="HI There!" name="Subject"><br>
  <textarea  id="message" placeholder="message" cols="30" rows="10" name="Message" > 
  </textarea> 
  <br>
  <input type="submit" id="send-btn" value="Send Message">
</form>
```

JQuery{3.4.1}

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
          $('form').on('submit', (e) =>{
              e.preventDefault();
              
              const fullName = $('#Fullname').val().trim();
              const phone = $('#phone').val().trim();
              const email = $('#email').val().trim();
              const subject = $('#subject').val().trim();
              const message = $('#message').val().trim();

              const data = {
                  fullName,
                  phone,
                  email,
                  subject,
                  message
              };

              $.post('/email', data, function(){
                  console.log('Server received our data')
              })
          })
      </script>
```

Mail.js (Responsible for handling apiKeys/domains and sending mail)

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const mailGun = require('nodemailer-mailgun-transport');
const config = require('./config.js');

// Credentials MailGun
const auth ={
 auth:{
    api_key: config.apiKey,
    domain: config.baseUrl

 }
};

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(auth);

const sendMail = (fullName,phone,email,subject,message,cb) =>{
 const mailOptions = {
    fullName,
    phone,
    from:'Collymore <erroldavids22@gmail.com>',
    email,
    subject,
    message
 };
 transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, data){
    if(err){
        cb(err,null);
    }else{
        cb(null, data);
    }
});
}
module.exports = sendMail;
```

whenever I access server.js like 'localhost:5000' from browser and try to send email from html form's data  to my email.

the browser's response back with `POST localhost:5000/email 500 internal error

I'm sorry for illustrating my problem in noobish way, and grammar too

Answer (score 0):

Passing only the `auth` parameters is possible but requires a call to [nodemailer-mailgun-transport](https://github.com/orliesaurus/nodemailer-mailgun-transport) (which you imported but didn't use):

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(mailGun(auth));
```

Comment: Now responding back with 405(method not allowed ) on browser

Comment: @ErrolDavids that's a new issue, you need to debug it and see what's returning the 405. Is it maingun? you can try adding to `mailOptions` the following key/value: `headers: { "Accept":  "application/json",  "Content-type":  "application/json" }`

Comment: Alright, i solved by using no backend form api, like formspree

Comment: @ErrolDavids it means it was a frontend problem (which is a different problem than the one you originally posted).